# Mapping request parameter name to action parameter with different name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have action method:

```
public ActionResult GetBook(int id){
...
}
```

It won't take this request because of wrong parameter name:

```
/controllerName/GetBook?bookId=3
```

I believe that it can be done somehow by configuring model binder.

I want that request parameter is being bound by both `"id"` and `"bookId"` names. 
In other words that this request is being passed:

```
/controllerName/GetBook?bookId=3
```

same as

```
/controllerName/GetBook?Id=3
```

Comment: You mean your code should come to the same method when you use either `/controllerName/GetBook?bookId=3` or `/controllerName/GetBook?id=3`?

Comment: can you explain the use case of why youd want to use a custom model binder over just changing the front end to passing an `id` or the controller action to taking a `int bookid`? Seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal yes, exactly.

Comment: @GregH actually there is no problem with it, I just want to know how it can be done, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to follow this design in the project, but since you just want to know whether it is possible or not, I guess you can do it in the following way.

Register a route in your RouteConfig.cs as follows

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "GetBook",
 "ControllerName/GetBook/{id}/{bookId}",
 new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "GetBook", id = UrlParameter.Optional, bookId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then in your controller, create an action method as follows

```
public ActionResult GetBook(int id = 0, int bookId = 0) {
    ...
}
```